# Double action when submitting a form in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, action

```
<div id="mainContent">
<iframe src="FormURL" height="2000" width="600" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

This iframe within my file form.php inputs a form on my webpage (FormURL is replaced by my actual URL). On sumbit the data from the from is submitted.

What I am looking to do is create a double action on submit so not only is the data submitted like it does at the moment when the user has clicked submit but ALSO calls mail.php, is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should submit the form to mail.php, then at the end of mail.php redirect to your form page.

```
// mail.php
// Process form...
header('location: form.php');
```

Otherwise you would need to handle the form submission event in javascript, serilise the form, use synchronous ajax to submit it to mail.php, then continue with form submission as normal.